# Refeshing JList Java after add Items

Tags: java, jlist

I'm trying to create simple addressbook with Java, I have JList that contain people's name, after successfully create person, the name of person will be show on JList, but it still didn't working.

Here's My AddressBookGUI code:

```
public class AddressBookGUI extends JFrame {
    // GUI components  
    private DefaultListModel<String> namaPeople = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<String> nameList = new JList<>(namaPeople);

    public AddressBookGUI() {
        JScrollPane listPane = new JScrollPane(nameList);
        getContentPane().add(listPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void addPerson(Person info) {
      // insert new Person's Name to JList
      // ERROR's Here
      DefaultListModel<String> namaPeople = new DefaultListModel<>();
      namaPeople.addElement(info.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to create a new `DefaultListModel` instance in the `static` method while you should use which one which exists if you want to add a `Person` and not overwriting the existing list.
Just use the `namaPeople` instance field to add it the new `Person`.
And remove also the `static` modifier here :

```
public static void addPerson(Person info)
```

because it prevents the method from accessing to a instance field.

```
public class AddressBookGUI extends JFrame {
    // GUI components  
    private DefaultListModel<String> namaPeople = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<String> nameList = new JList<>(namaPeople);

    public AddressBookGUI() {
        JScrollPane listPane = new JScrollPane(nameList);
        getContentPane().add(listPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

public void addPerson(Person info) {
    // insert new Person's Name to JList
    namaPeople.addElement(info.getName());
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i've update my code. Please check. I use that but showing error "Cannot make static refrence". addPerson(Person info) is inside AddressBookGUI

Comment: no problem :) I explain you the problem in the answer. The problem is the modifier of your method : `static`.

Comment: Giving me error like this "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method addPerson(Person) from the type AddressBookGUI". 
when i use AddressBookGUI.addPerson(new Person("John doe"))

Comment: You should not write  `AddressBookGUI.addPerson(new Person("John doe"));` but : `AddressBookGUI instance = new AddressBookGUI(); instance.addPerson(new Person("John doe"));` because `namaPeople` field  is a instance field, so you have to access it by a instance of your class and not from the class itself  : `AddressBookGUI`